# Android GoogleMaps API: IndexOutOfBoundsException in PolyUtil.decode()

Tags: java, android, google-maps, indexoutofboundsexception, google-polyline

I have an Android app with a GoogleMap and I want to draw a Polyline on it. For that I'm using [`PolyUtils.decode()`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#decode-java.lang.String-). But if it is called with my encoded String, I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

This is my piece of code:

```
private void drawPolyLine() {
    List<Trail> trails = mVehicle.getTrails();
    for (Trail trail : trails) {
        String encodedPolyline = trail.getTrail();
        String color = trail.getColor();
        List<LatLng> locations = PolyUtil.decode(encodedPolyline);
        Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .add(locations.toArray(new LatLng[locations.size()]))
                .width(5)
                .color(parseColor(color)));
    }
}
```

The encoded String that is passed to `PolyUtil.decode()` is:

```
"0ee24344-9647-4592-92e7-a51b71008f4b"
```

And the stack trace looks like this:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=36; index=36
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.String.indexAndLength(String.java:500)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:494)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.android.PolyUtil.decode(PolyUtil.java:313)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at net.my.domain.views.fragments.VehicleMapFragment.drawPolyLine(VehicleMapFragment.java:140)
 ...
```

What might possibly cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` like this? Is it my String that is invalid? How can I check whether or not an encoded Polyline String is valid? Can someone post me a valid example of a valid encoded Polyline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoded `String` that you are passing to `PolyUtil.decode()` does not seem to be a valid encoded polyline. It seems to be a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is caused the by an invalid encoded polyline.

Here is an example of encoding/decoding a polyline:

```
// Encoding
List<LatLng> locations2Encode = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
locations2Encode.add(new LatLng(40.1d, -3.1d));
locations2Encode.add(new LatLng(40.2d, -3.2d));
locations2Encode.add(new LatLng(40.3d, -3.3d));
locations2Encode.add(new LatLng(40.4d, -3.4d));
String encodedPolyline = PolyUtil.encode(locations2Encode);

// Decoding
List<LatLng> locations = PolyUtil.decode(encodedPolyline);
```

In this case the String representing the encoded polyline is

```
_`wsF~m|Q_pR~oR_pR~oR_pR~oR
```

According to the documentation it seems that there is no way to check if a encoded polyline is valid rather that decoding it.

You can find more examples and more info about encoding and decoding polylines in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm).

Comment: I think my string couldn't be more invalid...
So annoying that we don't get a meaningful Exception for that.

Comment: You are right... If you take a look at https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java you will see that `decode()` assumes that the String passed as parameter is valid and procceeds to happily decode it

Comment: Hey, but I am quite sure my encoded string is valid because I have taken it from the result of google directions API. here is the string               ed`tCknngN~BtArGdErAz@tB…@@DBH@B?B?L?jJQrACZA|@?

Answer (score 1):

Some encoded "overview_polyline" that we get from that directions response is encoded, has double encoded backslashes. To work in the request for a static map, the double \ needs to be translated to \

Try to converse here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility